# How do you install Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I am not very good with Ubuntu and clueless on how to install Virtualbox. Please help.

Comment: Use of ALL CAPITALS should only be used for STRONG EMPHASIS; or when it is VERY IMPORTANT.

Comment: or when SHOUTING at people.

Comment: What additional help, or instruction, are you going to need *to use* **VirtualBox**?

Answer (score 3):

open up software center and search for virtual box

[image: virtual box in ubuntu software center]

Answer (score 2):

Type the following in a terminal -

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox`